# Expand Pandas Dataframe adding rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| SEG | FAM | GAMA | MIN_RAT | MAX_RAT | VALOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1 | 2 | 5,15 |

And I need to "expand" the df adding new rows to make a new dataframe like this:

| SEG | FAM | GAMA | MIN_RAT | MAX_RAT | VALOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1 | 1 | **10,30** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,1 | 1,1 | **9,79** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,2 | 1,2 | **9,27** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,3 | 1,3 | **8,76** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,4 | 1,4 | **8,24** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,5 | 1,5 | **7,73** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,6 | 1,6 | **7,21** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,7 | 1,7 | **6,70** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,8 | 1,8 | **6,18** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 1,9 | 1,9 | **5,67** |
| PE | 001 | 002 | 2 | 2 | **5,15** |

The values ​​of the column "VALUE" are constructed dividing the 5.15 of the original table by the number of new rows and adding that value to 5.15 (in this case we add 0.515 in each row)

Is it possible to do this optimally?

Comment: I think in this case you mean column "VALOR" for "VALUE" right?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
rng = np.arange(df['MIN_RAT'].min(), df['MAX_RAT'].max()+.1, .1)
dfm = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(len(rng))).reset_index(drop=True)
dfm['MIN_RAT'] = rng
dfm['MAX_RAT'] = rng
step = df.loc[0,'VALOR'] / (len(rng)-1)
dfm['VALOR'] = [i * step + df.loc[0, 'VALOR'] for i in range(len(rng))][::-1]
dfm
```

Output:

```
   SEG  FAM  GAMA  MIN_RAT  MAX_RAT   VALOR
0   PE    1     2      1.0      1.0  10.300
1   PE    1     2      1.1      1.1   9.785
2   PE    1     2      1.2      1.2   9.270
3   PE    1     2      1.3      1.3   8.755
4   PE    1     2      1.4      1.4   8.240
5   PE    1     2      1.5      1.5   7.725
6   PE    1     2      1.6      1.6   7.210
7   PE    1     2      1.7      1.7   6.695
8   PE    1     2      1.8      1.8   6.180
9   PE    1     2      1.9      1.9   5.665
10  PE    1     2      2.0      2.0   5.150
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful! Can you see the question again if you can help me?

Comment: Sure, you can link with me on LinkedIn.  Or post on here again, and myself or anther great developer will help you.

Comment: If you don't mind and this post helped you, would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much... I'm a noob here... sorry... I'll repost the question!